# Creating Query like "A is "b" and C is '' " (Spring Boot/Spring Data w/Mongo)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm making a simple application with Spring Boot (2.3.4) using MongoDB with Spring Data for MongoDB. I usually create queries for the app using the @Query annotation and it works very fine. But for an Aggregation I want to use, I built a query with the Criteria class. The criteria I need is like

`where("primary").is(value).and("secondary").is("")`.

I need all entries where primary is equal to 'value' and secondary is empty. The query entered in   MOngoDB Compass

`{ $and: [ { primary: 'value' }, { secondary: ''} ] }`

works as expected, but when I try to use the Criteria with Spring, it looks like the and part with the secondary is completely dropped. I get any results with 'value' in *primary* and with anything in *secondary*. This means an empty fields or anything else. Replacing the `.is("")` part with `.regex("^$")` didn't help.

This looks pretty basic to me, so what am I missing here? I don't want to replace the empty secondary with an "empty flag", because that feels wrong.

**Update:**

This is the code in question

```
Criteria crit;
if(!primary.equals(secondary)) {
    crit = where("primary").is(primary.name()).and("secondary").is(secondary.name());
} else {
    crit = where("primary").is(primary.name()).and("secondary").is("");
}
MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(crit);
GroupOperation groupStage = Aggregation.group("grouping").count().as("sum");
SortOperation sortStage = new SortOperation(Sort.by("_id"));

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage, groupStage, sortStage);
AggregationResults<TypePerGroup> results =  mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "dataCollection",  TypePerGroup.class);
```

Comment: Could you provide the data returning incorrect results ?

Comment: Please post a sample input document showing the fields used in the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

This works with mongodb - Not sure what abstraction compass adds. Both queries don't generate the same json query but they are equal.

Generated query

```
where("primary").is(value).and("secondary").is("").
```

is

```
{"primary":value, "secondary": ""}
```

Perhaps compass doesn't like this variant ?

Anyways to generate query similar to what you have you input in compass you can use below code

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("primary").is("hello"), Criteria.where("secondary").is(""));
Query query = Query.query(criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not missing anything. `where("primary").is(value).and("secondary").is("")` is correct and is functionally equivalent to `{ $and: [ { primary: 'value' }, { secondary: ''} ] }`. You should turn on debug level logging for `MongoTemplate` to see the generated query.

Answer (score 0):

A have connected to Atlas using Mongo DBCompas and added 4 records to collection:

```
[{
  "primary": "A",
  "secondary": "A"
},{
  "primary": "A",
  "secondary": ""
},{
  "primary": "B",
  "secondary": "B"
},{
  "primary": "B",
  "secondary": ""
}]
```

both queries:

```
    List<Data> firstResults = mongoTemplate.query(Data.class)
            .matching(Query.query(Criteria.where("primary").is("B").and("secondary").is("")))
            .all();
    System.out.println(firstResults);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.andOperator(Criteria.where("primary").is("B"), Criteria.where("secondary").is(""));
    List<Data> secondResults = mongoTemplate.query(Data.class)
            .matching(Query.query(criteria))
            .all();
    System.out.println(secondResults);
```

gave the same result:

```
[Data{primary='B', secondary=''}]
```

Campfire can you please provide example of your code to analyze?

Comment: Yep, for a simple query it works fine indeed. But as soon as the rest of the aggregation is added, the result doesn't match the expected numbers. I added the snippet as you wanted me to.